# How to get to the right Tumblr blog from a Google search

Tags: google-search, tumblr

I am searching for the lyrics to a Darwin Deez song. I googled "I keep the mic on lockdown slavery deez" and in the description of the second result I can see the information that I want. When I click the link (a Tumblr link), it doesn't bring up the information given in the description, it just does a search for `#wonkybeats` in Tumblr.

How can I get to find these lyrics which are clearly in some Tumblr blog?

Answer (score 1):

Open Google’s cached version of the page. You should find the content there.

In this answer I described [how you can open the cached version](https://superuser.com/a/669835/151741) in Google.

Answer (score 0):

Google caches page content so what you are seeing isn't what is on http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/wonky-beats front page currently. You will have to go through scrolling down the never ending scroll and you should find it

[image: Searching Tumblr]

http://impossiblyblack.tumblr.com/post/3613705897/darwin-deez-i-dont-like-the-look-remix-i